# Why does Bash fail to redirect the output of time when the timed command triggers a shell exit?

Tags: bash

I have a command involving multiple redirections whose aim is to capture in a variable the output of Bash's `time` builtin while at the same time allowing the timed command to write to both stdout and stderr. Somehow the capture fails if the timed command triggers a shell exit but I can't find an explanation of why. I have found multiple workarounds but again I don't understand why they work.

Here is a stripped down version of the command that exposes the problem:

```
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time TIMED_COMMAND 2>&3); echo  "v=${v@Q}";
```

Thanks to the 3 redirections the `time` output is captured in the variable `v` while the timed command can still write to stderr. Here is an example:

```
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time { echo hello >&2; } 2>&3); echo "v=${v@Q}";
hello
v=$'\nreal\t0m0.002s\nuser\t0m0.000s\nsys\t0m0.000s'
```

However, the capture of the `time` output fails if the timed command triggers a shell exit:

```
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time exit 2>&3); echo "v=${v@Q}";

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
v=''
```

All of the following variations fail in the same manner:

```
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time { exit; } 2>&3); echo "v=${v@Q}";
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time { exit 2>&3; }); echo "v=${v@Q}";
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time (exit 2>&3)); echo "v=${v@Q}";
```

If the first redirection `3>&2` is replaced with `3>&1` or the third one `2>&3` with `2>&1`, then the `time` output is correctly captured. If the timed command `exit` is replaced with anything else that doesn't trigger a shell exit, like `true`, then too the `time` output is correctly captured.

I can't find any explanation for the failures. The last example is especially befuddling because the `exit` and the third redirection `3>&2` happen in a subshell. How can they have any impact on the behavior of `time`, which runs in a parent shell?!?

Finally here are variations where the `time` output is correctly captured:

```
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time eval "exit 2>&3"); echo "v=${v@Q}";
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time {(exit)} 2>&3); echo "v=${v@Q}";
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time {(exit) 2>&3; }); echo "v=${v@Q}";
$ v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time {(exit 2>&3)}); echo "v=${v@Q}";
```

But again, I have no clue why these work, while their slightly simpler alternatives fail.

So, just to be clear, I have found a way to achieve what I want. **What I'm looking for here, is an explanation of why the failing examples fail.**

I have tested all the examples on macOS 13.4 with Bash version 5.2.15(1)-release.

**Update 1**

The fact that `(time exit)` (or `time exit` but if you try that it will terminate your bash session) prints any stats is actually a bit surprising. Indeed, `exit` terminates the shell in which `time` runs. If the termination was immediate, no stats would be printed. Instead, Bash is smart enough to let the enclosing `time` finish its job before exiting. This works also for multiple enclosing `time`, like in `(time { time { time exit; }; }; echo FOO)`, which prints three times stats but no `FOO`: I used braces because consecutive `time` commands seem to be optimized into a single one: `(time time time exit)` only prints stats once.

Now, to come back to our problem, what seems to be going on is that Bash seems to fail to restore file descriptors on the way out in case an exit was triggered. When Bash executes `time : 2>/dev/null` it first redirects fd (file descriptor) `2` to `/dev/null`, then execute `:`, then restores f2 `2`, and finally executes the stats printing of `time`. The problem with `exit` seems to be that Bash fails to execute the fd restoration step. Thus `(time exit 2>/dev/null)` (or `(time { exit; } 2>/dev/null)`, or `(time { set -e; false; } 2>/dev/null)`) prints nothing (or rather prints stats into `/dev/null`). I guess this could be considered as a Bash bug.

If this explanation is correct, then it explains most of the examples described in my original question. However, it still doesn't explain why `(time (exit 2>/dev/null))` prints nothing. Here the redirection happens in a subshell of the one in which `time` runs. Whatever Bash does, or fails to do, in that subshell should have no effect on the shell in which `time` runs. Can subshells affect file descriptors of their parent shell?!? I don't think so and `(time (exit 2>/dev/null); echo FOO >&2)` prints `FOO` as expected (but no stats). The only explanation I can come up with for this case is that when the timed command starts with a subshell (i.e., with `(...)`), then Bash pushes the timing down to the subshell. In other words, Bash executes `(time (exit 2>/dev/null) )` as if it was `( (time exit 2>/dev/null) )`. This would also explain why `(time {(exit 2>/dev/null)})` prints stats because here the timing is kept in the parent shell.

Finally there remains the question of why `(time eval "exit 2>/dev/null")` prints stats. I suspect that this is because a forced exit out of `eval` is more careful and doesn't fail to restore file descriptors that need it. If the redirection happens outside of the `eval`, like in `(time eval "exit" 2>/dev/null)` (or `(time { eval "exit"; } 2>/dev/null)`), then no stats are printed.

Comment: The copy of `time` you're running is a shell builtin, not an external command. (There's a separate `/usr/bin/time`, but it's not what you're using here). A shell that has exited, of course, can't print anything.

Comment: Almost all your examples that succeed make only a subshell exit, not the copy of the shell that runs `time`, so their success is to be expected. The only one that's a surprise to me is the one with `eval`; I would have expected that to fail too; would need to dig into internals to see why, but `eval` deferring the effect of `exit` is undefined behavior anyhow, making it impractical to rely on (and we deal only in "practical, answerable questions about problems you actually face").

Comment: I'm well aware that I'm using the builtin. That's also my intention. I understand that exit may short-circuit some computations since it forces the shell in which it's running to immediately exit. However, that doesn't explain any of the behaviors described here.

Note that in all examples `time` prints its stats! And `echo "v=${v@Q}"`is always executed because the `exit` commands at most exist the subshell of the command substitution.

Comment: Consider for example `v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time exit 2>&3; echo FOO); echo "v=${v@Q}";`. Because of the exit "echo FOO" is never executed but how do you explain that the stats printed by the `time` command end up on stderr and not in `v`?

Comment: The example that truly befuddles me is this one: `v=$(exec 3>&2 2>&1; time (exit 2>&3); echo FOO >&2); echo "v=${v@Q}";`. Here `FOO` ends up in `v` but not the stats from `time`. And you can nest the exit in as many subshells as you want, it doesn't change the result. But put braces around any one of these subshells and it works!?!

Comment: The problem is demonstrated with just `time (exit 2>/dev/null)`.  That should produce timing output but doesn't.  It does produce output if `exit` is replaced with `:`.  I think this is a Bash bug.

Comment: Indeed, after a lot of thinking I figured that a possible explanation was that Bash failed to restore file descriptors on forced exits. This implied that `(time exit 2>/dev/null)` had to fail and indeed it failed. I added "Update 1" where I summarized my latest understanding of the problem.